# NSVisualEffectView disappears when using a layer-backed view

Tags: macos, core-animation, calayer, appkit, nsvisualeffectview

#### My goal

I would like to add a vibrancy effect to a collection view.

#### The setup

I have the following view hierarchy:

[image]

When I use this layout, the background has the vibrancy effect as expected, but the performance is not quite there.

`NSCollectionView` is optimized to work with layer-backed views, so I enable the `CALayer` on the collection view's enclosing scroll view.

#### The problem

If I do this, the visual effect view is no longer visible, and the collection view has a white background.

#### My question

Is there any way to make a layer-backed view work together with `NSVisualEffectView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if anyone's wondering, here's the trick:

- adding the `NSVisualEffectView`: correct
- making the enclosing scroll view layer-backed: correct
- enabling the scroll view to draw a background: **wrong**

Make sure to either set `drawsBackground` to false, or disable it in Interface Builder, and your collection view will have the vibrant background, and fast scrolling as well